# XML validation against XML schema: Cannot find the declaration of element 'tns:FlightMonitor'

Tags: xml, validation, xmlschemaset

I have a problem while trying to validate an XML file against a XML schema.
When I try a validation, the error who is reported is this one

```
Cannot find the declaration of element 'tns:FlightMonitor'
```

i don't know what I have to change, seems like that the XML schema is not correctly read or referenced in the xml file.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:FlightMonitor xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    tns:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo/ FDSInfo.xsd">

<Aircrafts>
    <aircraft>
        <model>E170</model>
        <seats>
            <seat>12A</seat>
            <seat>12B</seat>
            <seat>12C</seat>
            <seat>13A</seat>
            <seat>13B</seat>
            <seat>13C</seat>
            <seat>14A</seat>
            <seat>14B</seat>
            <seat>14C</seat>
        </seats>
    </aircraft>
    <aircraft>
        <model>A747</model>
        <seats>
            <seat>12A</seat>
            <seat>12B</seat>
            <seat>12C</seat>
            <seat>13A</seat>
            <seat>13B</seat>
            <seat>13C</seat>
            <seat>14A</seat>
            <seat>14B</seat>
            <seat>14C</seat>
        </seats>
    </aircraft>
</Aircrafts>

<Flights>
    <flightReader>
        <flightNumber>OV876</flightNumber>
        <departure>TRN</departure>
        <time>
            <hour>15</hour>
            <minute>30</minute>
        </time>
        <destination>LTN</destination>
    </flightReader>
    <flightReader>
        <flightNumber>OO076</flightNumber>
        <departure>MPX</departure>
        <time>
            <hour>9</hour>
            <minute>22</minute>
        </time>
        <destination>TRN</destination>
    </flightReader>
    <flightReader>
        <flightNumber>PV276</flightNumber>
        <departure>TRN</departure>
        <time>
            <hour>20</hour>
            <minute>00</minute>
        </time>
        <destination>MPX</destination>
    </flightReader>
    <flightReader>
        <flightNumber>OF376</flightNumber>
        <departure>LTN</departure>
        <time>
            <hour>13</hour>
            <minute>10</minute>
        </time>
        <destination>MPX</destination>
    </flightReader>
</Flights>

<FlightInstances>
    <flightInstanceReader>
        <flightID>OV876</flightID>
        <aircraftID>E170</aircraftID>   
        <date>14/2</date>
        <delay>0</delay>
        <departureGate>T12</departureGate>
        <status>BOARDING</status>
        <Passengers>
            <passengerReader>
                <name>Ivano Alvino</name>
                <seatID>12A</seatID>
                <boarded>true</boarded>
            </passengerReader>
            <passengerReader>
                <name>Maria Ingenerf</name>
                <seatID>12B</seatID>
                <boarded>true</boarded>
            </passengerReader>
            <passengerReader>
                <name>Giorgio Napolitano</name>
                <seatID>12C</seatID>
                <boarded>true</boarded>
            </passengerReader>
        </Passengers>
    </flightInstanceReader>
    <flightInstanceReader>
        <flightID>PV276</flightID>
        <aircraftID>B747</aircraftID>   
        <date>14/3</date>
        <delay>0</delay>
        <departureGate>T13</departureGate>
        <status>BOARDING</status>
        <Passengers>
            <passengerReader>
                <name>Alfonso Signorini</name>
                <seatID>12A</seatID>
                <boarded>true</boarded>
            </passengerReader>
            <passengerReader>
                <name>Geronimo Stilton</name>
                <seatID>12B</seatID>
                <boarded>true</boarded>
            </passengerReader>
            <passengerReader>
                <name>Cecchi Paone</name>
                <seatID>12C</seatID>
                <boarded>true</boarded>
            </passengerReader>
        </Passengers>
    </flightInstanceReader>
</FlightInstances>

</tns:FlightMonitor>
```

XML schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo" >

    <!-- Simple Types Declaration -->
    <!-- ************************ -->

    <simpleType name="stringType">
      <restriction base="string" />
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="modelType">
      <restriction base="string">
        <pattern value="[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]" />
      </restriction>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="seatType">
      <restriction base="string">
        <pattern value="[0-9][0-9][A-Z]" />
      </restriction>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="flightNumberType">
      <restriction base="string">
        <pattern value="[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]" />
      </restriction>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="hourType">
      <restriction base="integer">
        <minInclusive value="0" />
        <maxInclusive value="23" />
      </restriction>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="minuteType">
      <restriction base="integer">
        <minInclusive value="0" />
        <maxInclusive value="59" />
      </restriction>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="delayType">
      <restriction base="integer"/>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="statusType">
        <restriction base="string">
          <enumeration value="ARRIVED"/>
          <enumeration value="BOARDING"/>
          <enumeration value="BOOKING"/>
          <enumeration value="CANCELLED"/>
          <enumeration value="CHECKINGIN"/>
          <enumeration value="DEPARTED"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>



    <!-- Aircraft -->   
    <!-- ******** -->

    <complexType name="seatsType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="seat" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:seatType" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="aircraftType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="model" type="tns:modelType"/>
        <element name="seats" type="tns:seatsType"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="AircraftsType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="aircraft" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:aircraftType" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>


    <!-- Flights -->
    <!-- ******* -->    

    <complexType name="timeType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="hour" type="tns:hourType" />
        <element name="minute" type="tns:minuteType" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="flightReaderType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="flightNumber" type="tns:flightNumberType" />
        <element name="departure" type="tns:stringType" />
        <element name="time" type="tns:timeType" />
        <element name="destination" type="tns:stringType" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="FlightsType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="flightReader" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:flightReaderType" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>


    <!-- FlightInstances -->
    <!-- *************** -->

    <complexType name="passengerReaderType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="name" type="tns:stringType" />
        <element name="seatID" type="tns:seatType" />
        <element name="boarded" type="boolean" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="PassengersType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="passengerReader" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:passengerReaderType" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="flightInstanceReaderType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="flightID" type="tns:flightNumberType" />
        <element name="aircraftID" type="tns:modelType" />
        <element name="date" type="date" />
        <element name="delay" type="tns:delayType" />
        <element name="departureGate" type="tns:stringType" />
        <element name="status" type="tns:statusType" />
        <element name="Passengers" type="tns:PassengersType" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="FlightInstancesType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="flightInstanceReader" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:flightInstanceReaderType" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>


    <!-- FlightMonitor -->
    <!-- *************** -->

    <complexType name="FlightMonitorType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="Aircrafts" type="tns:AircraftsType" />
        <element name="Flights" type="tns:FlightsType" />
        <element name="FlightInstances" type="tns:FlightInstancesType" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>


    <!-- Root -->
    <!-- **** -->

    <element name="FlightMonitor" type="tns:FlightMonitorType" />

</schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue, I changed the first line of XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:FlightMonitor xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    tns:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo/ FDSInfo.xsd">
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:FlightMonitor xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo/ FDSInfo.xsd ">
```

and changed also the first lines of XML schema from this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo" >
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo/"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/FDSInfo/">
```